# Magento 2.4.2: Where to configure to allow shipping to a new country?

Tags: magento2.3

We are as of now shipping only within the US. Since we decided to ship also to Canada, where in Magento admin do we need to configure shipping to new countries?

The screenshot below shows only US without any other country. I don't see where to set this. Could you please suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure which countries customers are allowed to create addresses for:

*Stores > Configuration > General > Country Options > Allow Countries*

(See the note below about scope.)

You can *further* configure shipping to specific countries for each available shipping method (UPS, FedEx, etc.)

E.g. if:

*Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Ups > Ship to Applicable Countries*

is set to "Specific Countries", you can specify those countries under:

*Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Ups > Ship to Applicable Countries*

**Note about scope:**

In Magento 2.4.2, the configuration field for:

*Stores > Configuration > General > Country Options > Allow Countries*

is only available at the default and website scope:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.2/app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L223

If your database has store scope data saved (as did mine), it will be invisible to admin users, but still applicable by Magento(!)

This can be remedied by

1. Editing
   `vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` to add
   `showInStore="1"` to the config field (line 223 in Magento
   2.4.2) and clearing the cache.
2. Now that the config is visible from the store scope, check the "Use Website" checkbox.
3. Revert the system.xml edit and clear the cache.

The store scope value should no longer override the website value.

Comment: Thanks, please check my updated post.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. I added additional info, including an odd scope issue that I ran into while testing.

Answer (score 2):

Before configuring shipping method you need to know shipping type as well, there are two type of shipping methods.

1. Offline Shipping Method (Free Shipping, Table Rate etc.)
2. Online Shipping Method (UPS, FedEx etc.)

The most important point for configuring online shipping method is that you required some credentials like, access key and  authentication token types of details.

In Magento you can configure it from following path.

On the Admin Panel, **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
On the left panel, under **Sales**, select **Shipping Methods** tab.

These are the steps from where you can configure offline and online shipping methods.

Comment: Thanks, please check my updated post.